# Promise returning empty value from Firestore when data is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have an asynchronous function that is called and a list of user ids are passed as an argument. The function queries firestore to get the token for the user id within that iteration.

```js
async function getTokensForUsers(ids) {
  const promises = ids.map(async (id) => {
    console.log("Querying for user with id: " + id);
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection('users').where('deviceUid', '==', id).get();
    return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().deviceToken);
  });
  let tokens = await Promise.all(promises);
  return tokens.flat();
}
```

This method is called as follows:

```js
const ids = await getIdsOfUsersWithName(name);
console.log("Getting tokens for users" + ids);
const tokens = await getTokensForUsers(ids);
console.log("Tokens" + tokens)
```

When the final `console.log()` prints, it prints as "Tokens,,,,," suggesting that it hasn't returned the data from the Promise, when I can see the data within the collection.

Comment: can you tale a look at my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated this issue from the code you have provided and got the intended result. I have tried with both firebase V9(Modular) and with firebase V8(namespaced).

This issue seems to have the `deviceToken` field being empty in the firestore database collection. I recommend you to change this line

```
return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().deviceToken);
```

to

```
const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().deviceToken);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
```

This will show you what is being returned from the `doc.data().deviceToken` of each document and as you mentioned you are getting "Tokens,,,,," which means you will probably will get something like this :

```
[ '' ]
[ '' ]
[ '' ]
[ '' ]
[ '' ]
Tokens,,,,
```

Which seems like your `deviceToken` field is empty.
Here’s my code which successfully worked.:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();

async function getTokensForUsers(ids) {
  const promises = ids.map(async (id) => {
    console.log("Querying for user with id: " + id);
    const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection("users")
      .where("deviceUid", "==", id)
      .get();
    const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().deviceToken);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
  let tokens = await Promise.all(promises);
  return tokens.flat();
}

const name = "rohit";
async function fire() {
  const ids = await getIdsOfUsersWithName(name);
  console.log("Getting tokens for users: " + ids);
  const tokens = await getTokensForUsers(ids);
  console.log("Tokens" + tokens);
}

async function getIdsOfUsersWithName(name) { //assumed
  const querySnapshot = await db
    .collection("users")
    .where("name", "==", name)
    .get();
  return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().deviceUid);
}
fire();
```